# Is there a button UI design tutorial?

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, usability

I've been browsing for a tutorial that covers basic button UI design (e.g. colors, effects, and etc.). Since I'm designing a component of my own, I was hoping there was some sort of tutorial that could guide me in making the correct design choices (aesthetically speaking...).

For instance, this tutorial should be able to guide me in answering some of the following questions:

1. What should a button look like when it's pressed?
2. What should a button look like when it's hovered over?

I tagged this as a Java Swing-specific question since that's the language that I will be utilizing. And yes, I've used the existing component behavior as a guideline, but I would like something more definitive.

Note: this tutorial does not need to be Java Swing-specific!

Something like [this](http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/how-to-design-buttons-to-help-improve-usability/).

Comment: Good question; note that Swing buttons are UI-specific, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Look & Feel Design Guidelines has some detail on button image design:

http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/hig-142056.html#52291  (thanks [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166992/olivier-faucheux) for supplying an updated link)

Comment: The actual links seems to be http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hig-142056.html#52291

Answer (score 0):

You should look on UI templates and choose something that look appropriate (even on website template and flash), and then customize the swing components according to this look.

if your want your gui to look a little bit more updated, try [swingx](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/)

check their UI it look pretty good.

Comment: I'm really just looking for a tutorial that informs one on what constitutes a "good" button design (including LaF, behavior, and etc.).